# C++ Avoid Rounding Number

Tags: c++, decimalformat

I know we can use `setprecision` to prevent a number to be rounded but what if I don't want to round all of my numbers in the list with the same decimal places? In other words, I want to keep my numbers the same as calculated and each number has its own decimal places.

For example: if we use `setprecision(7)` then it will give the output up to 7 decimal places for all numbers in my list. What if I have a list of different numbers with different decimal places such as 8 or 10 decimal places? Do I need to do `setprecision` for each of them? Is there any way to keep my numbers the same as the output after calculated? `Ex:0.1234567, 0.123456789, 0.12345678910`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   vector<double> myVec{0.1234567, 0.123456789, 0.12345678, 0.12345678910};

   for(int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); i++)
   {
       cout << myVec[i] << " ";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a small code sample which illustrated your point. 10 lines of code = 100 words, after all.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep my numbers the same as calculated"?  Decimal places are not part of the number stored in memory.

Comment: `setprecision` controls output but has no effect on the number, hence your quesiton is rather unclear

Comment: @mackycheese21 I added the code, I want to keep my output the same as the myVec.

Comment: You know that the values you set are not really the ones stored in memory? If not, check out [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a vector of string representations of numbers rather than a vector of doubles.

Comment: @Keldorn Thank you for giving me that link, really helpful. I also want the output the same as the myVec but it keeps rounding. I do not want to setprecision for each element because each element has its own decimal places length. I hope you see what I mean :(

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to keep my numbers the same as the output after calculated?

Not with floating point types such as `double`.

These are binary floating points, not decimal. Many exact finite decimal fractions will convert to infinite binary fraction, and rounding would happen. So after you do `dobule d = 0.1234567`, the variable `d` will not contain exactly `0.1234567`, it is rather something close to `0.1234567` representable as double.

A way to deal with this is to have custom data types that are decimal fractions, with fixed or floating point, so that `0.1234567` could be represented exactly.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. I hope I can know a specific "super data type" for that but I don't think C++ has. :((

Comment: Standard C++ does not, but there are libraries. Look at boost multiprecision. `cpp_dec_float_50` may be what you want.